# display a list in a different format

Tags: python, formatting

I'm trying to display a list in a different format.

so for example.

```
function(list):
```

The user inputs a list of numbers like `[0,1,2]` and instead of returning `"[0,1,2]"` it returns `"0 1 2"` with no brackets and no commas.

Answer (score 5):

```
def format(lst):
    return ' '.join(str(x) for x in lst)
```

For example:

```
>>> format([1, 2, 3])
'1 2 3'
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
print(' '.join(map(str,lst)))
```

Note the white space between the single quotes, that's what is used to "glue" each `str(element)` with the `join` string method.